# Rails 3 development site is 10x faster than production site on Apache 2 + Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger

I have a live production site (production mode) running alongside a test site running in development mode. They both run on the same machine, using Rails 3, Apache 2 and Phusion Passenger. If I load the same page on the production site, it takes approximately 4-5 seconds to load the page. If I request the same page on the test site it takes (only) about 0.5 seconds. A major difference of 10x. Always thought that production would be faster than development :( If I reload the page on the production site the load times stay the same. What is going on? How can I debug this problem? Because as of now the production site is way too slow even without any traffic.

I did some additional testing with other web servers, in particular Litespeed and even Webbrick. Both exhibit the same strange behaviour. Ten time slower in production mode than in development mode. So it probably is something Rails related. But I can not put my finger on it. Since the logs tell me the pages are rendered quickly, but it takes a hell of a lot of time before the page appears on my screen.

Comment: The "Net" panel in Firebug has a very nice breakdown of how time is spent on each request.  That'll let you see if any particular sub-request is the culprit.  Might be a good place to start?

Comment: Besides Firebug, I would suggest adding New Relic performance monitoring. It checks both which parts of your rails code are running slow, and also checks performance between the server and end user's browser. Sometimes the bulk of the time can be sending individual assets over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. I managed to get it fixed. I finally decided to load all my production data to my development server. It turned out that my sessions table was the culprit. It contained a lot of data and querying was slow. I added an index and the problem was solved.